# Excel. Convert text to values and calculate the values in a formula

Tags: excel, type-conversion

I want to convert text to values and then with this values calculate a result:
Text "A" is always = 8
Text "B" is always =7

In my sheet:
In cell A1:"A" and in B1: "B". Now in cell C1 I want the sum of A1 and B1 (8+7=15).

I always want the cells A1 och B1 to show text not values. 
And if it possible I dont want any intermediate cells that convert A1 to 8 and B1 to 7 so the resultformula points at that intermdediate cells. I want my result (C1) to calculate the text cells directly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(A1="A",8,IF(A1="B",7,NA()))*IF(B1="A",8,IF(B1="B",7,NA()))
```

It is easier to have a separate translation list, say on Sheet2 cells A1:B6:

A   8

B   7

C   6

D   5

E   4

F   3

and then use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$6,2,FALSE)*VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$6,2,FALSE)
```